# Unable to read Http request using ECHO

Tags: go, swagger-codegen

I created the Swagger API Definition file using the Swagger API-codegen. However, I am getting an error when I try to pass the request. Can someone plz tell me where am I making mistake? and how can I read the data?

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    api "newform-api/inputform"

    "github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen/pkg/middleware"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    echomiddleware "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
)

// ServerInterface represents all server handlers.
type ServerInterface interface {
    Externalhealthcheck(ctx echo.Context) error
    NewFormEntry(ctx echo.Context) error
}

func main() {
    var port = flag.Int("port", 8080, "Port for test HTTP server")
    flag.Parse()

    swagger, err := api.GetSwagger()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error loading swagger spec\n: %s", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    swagger.Servers = nil

    apiData := api.ServerInterfaceWrapper{}

    e := echo.New()
    e.Use(echomiddleware.Logger())

    e.Use(middleware.OapiRequestValidator(swagger))

    api.RegisterHandlers(e, apiData.Handler)
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(fmt.Sprintf("0.0.0.0:%d", *port)))
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
⇨ http server started on [::]:8080
echo: http: panic serving [::1]:49238: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 5 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00007a000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x14f74e0, 0x18bed00)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
newform-api/inputform.(*ServerInterfaceWrapper).Externalhealthcheck(...)
    /Users/kaka/Desktop/go/src/github.com/nousher/newform-api/inputform/openapi_server.gen.go:30
github.com/labstack/echo/v4.(*Echo).add.func1(0x1621b60, 0xc00007a0a0, 0x1610240, 0xc000262840)
    /Users/kaka/go/pkg/mod/github.com/labstack/echo/v4@v4.5.0/echo.go:544 +0x62
github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen/pkg/middleware.OapiRequestValidatorWithOptions.func1.1(0x1621b60, 0xc00007a0a0, 0x18d1340, 0xa0)
    /Users/kaka/go/pkg/mod/github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen@v1.9.0/pkg/middleware/oapi_validate.go:86 +0xe8
github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware.LoggerWithConfig.func2.1(0x1621b60, 0xc00007a0a0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/kaka/go/pkg/mod/github.com/labstack/echo/v4@v4.5.0/middleware/logger.go:117 +0x130
github.com/labstack/echo/v4.(*Echo).ServeHTTP(0xc000147200, 0x1619600, 0xc000288000, 0xc000280000)
    /Users/kaka/go/pkg/mod/github.com/labstack/echo/v4@v4.5.0/echo.go:654 +0x182
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc00019c2a0, 0x1619600, 0xc000288000, 0xc000280000)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2843 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc00007a000, 0x161a800, 0xc000030080)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1925 +0x8ad
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2969 +0x36c
```

API Definition Files:
https://github.com/Nosh786/api-descriptions/tree/main/inputform

Comment: post the rest of the error message, it should have a line number where the nil pointer dereference is happening.  I don't see any calls of `Externalhealthcheck()` so I am guessing the error is not in the stuff you are including

Comment: Apologies, just posted the complete error message. @DanielFarrell